# Python3 global scoping in different modules

Tags: python, python-3.x, scope, global

I would like to clarify, how globals from different modules are scoped?

I failed to find relevant documentation for this matter, thus I am relying on observation, but I would like to have some more insight, if my findings are pure implementation coincidence, or if I can trust them?

Testcase:

module_1.py:

```
global_var1 = 'm1_v1'
global_var2 = 'm1_v2'

def f():
 print('f: {}'.format(global_var1))
 print('f: {}'.format(global_var2))
```

module_2.py:

```
import module_1

global_var1 = 'm2_v1'

def g():
 print('g: {}'.format(global_var1))
 print('g: {}'.format(global_var2))

module_1.f()

g()
```

`$ python3 module_2.py`

```
f: m1_v1
f: m1_v2
g: m2_v1
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "module_2.py", line 11, in <module>
    g()
  File "module_2.py", line 7, in g
    print('g: {}'.format(global_var2))
NameError: name 'global_var2' is not defined
```

#### Conclusion:

Thus, my conclusion is that a function will use the globals in this order:

1. <strike>the module where the function is used</strike>
2. the module where the function is defined (EDIT: this is the only answer!)

<strike>Globals are not bleeding through from imported modules.</strike>

EDIT: Functions imported from other modules bring their module globals like a closure.

#### Question:

I would like to see some comprehensive documentation on this matter (which I failed to find...).

While testing this out is nice, I have no idea, if this is a freak coincidence, and this behavior should never be trusted, or this is the expected way?

Also, what if a function is somehow imported through a 3rd module? what if the function is a class method? Etc.etc.

If you can't point me to a documentation, but you know a guideline "for sure", I am interested, as well.

---

I won't go in lengths why and how I want to use this, I am primarily interested to better understand the workings of python. However, if you do know a better solution, given the information at hand, I am interested to see that, as well - it will NOT be accepted as an answer, though.

---

In case there is a difference between python2 and python3, my main interest is python3, but it is nice to have the info on python2, as well.

Comment: How do you conclude 1.? Your test does not match this. Did you read the documentation on [name resolution](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/executionmodel.html#resolution-of-names)?

Comment: Ops, you are right! (in an earlier test, some 1-s and 2-s got swapped, landed me in the wrong conclusion, and I was blind to the real result, after that, thank you for pointing out!!!)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

TLDR: Python uses [lexical/static scoping](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scope_(computer_science)#Lexical_scope_vs._dynamic_scope) since Python 2.1, including Python 3. (See [name resolution](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/executionmodel.html#resolution-of-names) and [PEP 227](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0227/))

---

Lexical scoping means functions only have access to the enclosing scopes *in which they are defined*, up to their module’s global namespace. Only the [`builtins`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/builtins.html) are visible in all modules. The global namespace of modules is not shared, and importing or calling a function in another module does not give it access to that namespace.

Some peculiarities worth pointing out:

- Local/function scopes are defined when the function is parsed. Names are either local, closures/nonlocal, or global.
- Global/module scopes are mutable. Names can be added, removed or changed at any time.
- Classes introduce short-lived scopes that are not visible to functions or other classes defined inside them.

Answer (score 2):

Each module has its own global scope. Let's look at the second module:

```
import module_1

global_var1 = 'm2_v1'

def g():
 print('g: {}'.format(global_var1))
 print('g: {}'.format(global_var2))

module_1.f()

g()
```

Since `global_var1` and `global_var2` aren't local variables, they are looked up in the global scope. Since `module_2.global_var2` isn't defined, you get a `NameError`.

You would either need to create `module_2.global_var2` with something like `from module_1 import global_var2`, or change the definition of `g` to

```
def g():
    print('g: {}'.format(global_var1))
    print('g: {}'.format(module_1.global_var2))
```

`import module_1` only adds one name to the global scope of `module_2`, that being `module_1`, which refers to the `module` object created by the `import` statement. `from module_1 import global_var2` *also* only adds one name, `global_var2`, which is *initialized* to the value of `module1.global_var2` (though with the side effect of creating a new module). In this case, `module1.global_var2` and `module2.globar_var2` are two *distinct* objects, not two names for the same object.