# Python 3 - substituting functions for print()

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm trying to write a replacement for the `print()` function; I'd like to understand what Python 3 is doing here.

Consider the following two Python 3 source files:

file.py:

```
def in_a_file():
    print("this is in a file")
```

minimal.py:

```
import builtins
from file import *

def test():
    print("this is a test")

def printA(*args, **kwargs):
    builtins.print("A: ", end="")
    builtins.print(*args, **kwargs)

print = printA

test()
in_a_file()
```

When I run minimal.py, I get this output:

```
A: this is a test
this is in a file
```

So, clearly, the assignment `print=printA` has changed the behavior of `print()` in function `test()`, but not in function `file()`.

Why?

And, is there code I could put in minimal.py that would similarly change the behavior of `print()` in function `file()`?

Comment: A module has its own namespace, it doesn't use the variables defined in the file that imports it.

Comment: @Barmar I suppose you're correct, but can you please elaborate? I don't understand how "it doesn't use the variables defined in the file that imports it" explains what I'm seeing. Or how to get the behavior I want - which is to change the way print() in the module works.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Python3 global scoping in different modules](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60352980/python3-global-scoping-in-different-modules/60353153#60353153)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Short description of the scoping rules?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/291978/short-description-of-the-scoping-rules)

Comment: Every module has its own namespace where it looks up variable names. So the variable `print` in your file is not the same as the one in `file.py`. This is done so that module authors don't have to worry that their variables might conflict with variables in the caller.

Comment: As for your second question: Do you want to change ``print`` only in ``file`` or in all modules?

Comment: @MisterMiyagi: I'd like to change 'print' in all modules. If I need to specify which modules specifically to make this work, I can do that.

Comment: When `test` is called, it uses whatever the name `print` is bound to at that time, not what `print` was bound to when `test` was defined.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The name lookup is roughly `builtins` shared by all modules, each module's own `global` namespace, and then subsequently nested function/class namespaces. The `print` function lives in `builtins`, and is thus visible in all modules by default.

The assignment `print = printA` in `minimal.py` adds a new name `print` to `minimal`'s global namespace. This means `minimal.print` shadows `builtins.print` *inside the `minimal` module*. The change is not visible in any other module, since each has a separate module-global namespace.

To change `print` across all modules, re-assign `builtins.print`.

```py
import builtins

_real_print = builtins.print

def printA(*args, **kwargs):
    _real_print("A: ", end="")
    _real_print(*args, **kwargs)

builtins.print = printA
```

Comment: Another possibility is to do file.print = printA.